# Output of the Sugar & Sulfuric Acid Reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, combustion

When a reaction of sugar and sulfuric acid occurs, some form of carbon is produced. Is this carbon bonded as graphite? If not, than what is it bonded as?

$\ce{C6H12O6 ->[H2SO4] 6C + 6 H2O }$

Comment: @A.K. Wow, that was really dumb of me, I didn't double check my chemical reaction and somehow convinced myself that carbon was the output.

Comment: @A.K. Revised question to valid chemical equation.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/how-does-sulfuric-acid-dehydrate-sugars

Answer (score 3):

The product is not pure elemental carbon, but instead an [amorphous solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_solid) that consists of *mostly* carbon atoms, with at least 5-10% of the atoms being other elements.  For example, [one academic paper from 2001](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jong-Sung_Yu/publication/244317825_Ordered_uniform_porous_carbon_by_carbonization_of_sugars._Carbon/links/0c960537a259a295db000000.pdf) found that the "carbon" formed by sulfuric acid catalyzed dehydration of sugar had a $\ce{C}:\ce{H}$ molar ratio of 14:1.

Such materials are sometimes called [hydrogenated amorphous carbon](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925963595002731).