# Why Does Adding Catalyst Slow Down My Reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, catalysis, mixtures

I currently did a lab where I was meant to identify factors that increase the rate of the reaction. I reacted Glucose with Potassium Permanganate and used Sulfuric Acid as a catalyst. But in my recordings I found that the more catalyst I added to my mixture, the slower the reaction took to reach its endpoint. Is there any reason why a reaction may take longer to reach endpoint when more catalyst is added?

Comment: If there is no reason why this may occur, could you also let me know if I did my experiment wrong?

Comment: [Too many chefs in the kitchen could spoil the mix](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/how-does-sulfuric-acid-dehydrate-sugars).